# How does Visual Studio determine what to delete during clean?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, build-process

I've got some issues with building my current solution after migrating from VS2010 to VS2013, and while trying to figure them out, I've stumbled upon something odd: I have a setup where I have a web application project called `UserInterface`, and a bunch of small web app projects which are physically located inside the `UserInterface` folder and are set to build into `UserInterface`'s bin folder.

I've noticed while examining build logs that during the clean phase, all of UI's child projects just delete files related to them (e.g. project `Whatever` would delete `\UserInterface\bin\Whatever.dll`, `\UserInterface\Whatever\obj\Debug\bunchoffiles.ext`, etc). The project named `Main`, however, on clean deletes *everything* in the `UserInterface` bin folder.

I have a feeling that this is related to - or the cause of - my build issues, but I can't figure out why it happens. How does VS determine this?

Comment: Putting more than one project in the same folder is a mistake.  Unless you don't mind having to rebuild them.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not authorised to change that in this solution, so I can't really do anything about it.